# Defining Unit Vectors in Spherical Coordinates for use with Eigen3

Tags: eigen3, spherical-coordinate

I'm posting here because I'm at a bit of a loss

I'm trying to implement a [solution to Maxwells equations (p47 2-2)](http://etheses.whiterose.ac.uk/4169/1/uk_bl_ethos_270894.pdf)

[image: Formula Link Latex],

which is given in Spherical coordinates in C++ so it may be used in a larger modeling project. I'm using Eigen3 as a base for linear algebra, which as far as I can find doesn't explicitly support spherical coordinates (I'm open to alternatives)

To implement the solution I need (or at least i think i need) to define the spherical unit vectors as spherical coordinates however, as [they're not constants](https://www.cpp.edu/~ajm/materials/delsph.pdf) like in Cartesian Coordinates and I don't understand how to do this.

I'm hesitant to convert the solution to Cartesian coordinates as I don't think I understand the implications of doing this (is it even valid?)

Any and all input and advice is appreciated

Comment: Please include all relevant information into the question itself. Not many will be willing to scan through large external documents (which in the the future may even become unavailable).

Comment: thanks @chtz, Im still less than 10 rep so i can't add an image, which prevents me from putting an excerpt of the paper, or a formula in the question (as SO doesn't have latex support directly), I've added links to a latex parser and an imgr link to the formula and the excerpt. is there a better way to include this information more clearly in future?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, which seems obvious now I have found it, is to implement [Spherical Unit Vector Identities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYVbB.png) as 3 functions (one for each unit vector) that takes r, Theta, and Phi as arguments and return a vector.